# Injector vs ViewContainerRef.injector vs ViewContainerRef.parentInjector

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Suppose we have the following:

```
@Directive({ selector: "[appSome]" })
export class SomeDirective {
    public constructor(
        private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
        private injector: Injector,
    ) {
      console.log(`injector === viewContainerRef.injector: ${injector === viewContainerRef.injector}`);
      console.log(`injector === viewContainerRef.parentInjector: ${injector === viewContainerRef.parentInjector}`);
      console.log(`viewContainerRef.injector === viewContainerRef.parentInjector: ${viewContainerRef.injector === viewContainerRef.parentInjector}`);
    }
}
```

What is the difference between those 3 injectors?

1. `this.injector`
2. `this.viewContainerRef.injector`
3. `this.viewContainerRef.parentInjector`

In the test above they all are different instances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the **Injector** you're getting in constructor is so-called [Merge Injector](https://twitter.com/AngularInDepth/status/1006062460175044608).

Here is it's [definition](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/235a235fab45b2c82f8758fc9c0779f62a5b6c04/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L332):

```
class Injector_ implements Injector {
  constructor(private view: ViewData, private elDef: NodeDef|null) {}
  ...
}
```

Angular just takes view data and node definition and can instantiate Injector instance whenever it's demanded via [createInjector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6ef9f2278f64697920df8ecaf79293a7eef7e0ab/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L328) function:

```
export function createInjector(view: ViewData, elDef: NodeDef): Injector {
  return new Injector_(view, elDef);
}
```

Now let come back to your directive:

```
                                 SomeDirective 
                                     |
                                    deps
                               /            \
                        Injector         ViewContainer
```

To create directive instance Angular resolves dependenies through dedicated function [resolveDep](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6ef9f2278f64697920df8ecaf79293a7eef7e0ab/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L326)

```
export function resolveDep(view, elDef) {
  ...
  case ViewContainerRefTokenKey:
     return asElementData(searchView, elDef.nodeIndex).viewContainer;
  ...
  case InjectorRefTokenKey:
     return createInjector(searchView, elDef);
  ...
}
```

Let's assume you have a component like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h2 appSome>Hello</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

In this case:

```
                                SomeDirective 
                                     |
                                    deps
                               /               \
                   Injector                      ViewContainer
                      ||                              ||
                      \/                              \/
  resolveDep(AppComponent view, h2 elDef)       resolveDep(AppComponent view, h2 elDef)
                      ||                              ||    
                      \/                              \/   
                 createInjector               viewContainerRef (AppComponent view, h2 elDef)
                                               (created early)
                      ||
                      \/
      new Injector(AppComponent view, h2 elDef)
```

`ViewContainerRef` instance was created early during view node creation. Since you require `ViewContainerRef` through DI Angular marks `h2` node with special flag and this way it can instantiate `ViewContainerRef` and [store](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/core/src/view/view.ts#L277) this instance in h2 node data.

```
if (nodeDef.flags & 16777216 /* EmbeddedViews */) {
   nodeData.viewContainer = createViewContainerData(view, nodeDef, nodeData);
}
```

where [createViewContainerData](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/235a235fab45b2c82f8758fc9c0779f62a5b6c04/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L125):

```
export function createViewContainerData(
    view: ViewData, elDef: NodeDef, elData: ElementData): ViewContainerData {
  return new ViewContainerRef_(view, elDef, elData);
}
```

So what we have here: `Injector` and `ViewContainer` that point to the same view and the same elDef.

Now let's look at ViewContainerRef [definition](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/235a235fab45b2c82f8758fc9c0779f62a5b6c04/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L130):

```
class ViewContainerRef_ implements ViewContainerData {
  ...
  constructor(private _view: ViewData, private _elDef: NodeDef, private _data: ElementData) {}
  ...
  get injector(): Injector { return new Injector_(this._view, this._elDef); }

  get parentInjector(): Injector {
    let view = this._view;
    let elDef = this._elDef.parent;
    while (!elDef && view) {
      elDef = viewParentEl(view);
      view = view.parent !;
    }

    return view ? new Injector_(view, elDef) : new Injector_(this._view, null);
  }
  ...
}
```

### Case 1

```
injector === viewContainerRef.injector  => fail
```

Because **viewContainerRef.injector getter creates new instance** of Injector with the same view and elDef.

So the following is true:

```
injector.view === viewContainerRef.injector.view
injector.elDef === viewContainerRef.injector.elDef
```

### Case 2

```
injector === viewContainerRef.parentInjector => fail
```

Because parentInjector getter will get new instance of Injector with parent view and parent elDef.

Parent view here is host view and elDef is my-app.

### Case 3

```
viewContainerRef.injector === viewContainerRef.parentInjector  => fail
```

Should be obvious that they are not equal since point to the different view and elDef too and are created through `new` operator.

---

Finally, you can read:

**[What you always wanted to know about Angular Dependency Injection tree](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-dependency-injection-and-tree-shakeable-tokens-4588a8f70d5d)**